# Line break tags are added between inline elements in Wordpress, resulting in broken layout

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am styling some download links which when tested in JSfiddle, appear to be ok. However, when the same code in inserted into WordPress, for some reason the .title class is forced outside the container?

Website: http://79.170.44.103/113events-temp.co.uk/cotswold-113/downloads/

Thanks in advance.

```css
.item-listing .item {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 20px 10px 0 110px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.item-listing .item:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.item-listing .item .icon {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 3rem;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.item-listing .item .title {
    color: #222222;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.item-listing .item .subtitle {
    color: #b4b4b4;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-listing">
  <a href="#" class="item type-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Document Title</span>
    <span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item type-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Document Title</span>
    <span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item type-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Document Title</span>
    <span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item type-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Document Title</span>
    <span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="item type-link" target="_blank">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span>
    <span class="title">Document Title</span>
    <span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: how are you inputting it? through the editor? it seems like `<br>` tags are being added

Comment: Yes, through the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the WordPress editor can be buggy when you're switching between the "text" and "visual" editors. Since `span` is an inline element, the only thing I've found to fix the problem (without completely disabling `wpautop`) is to make the code inline:

```
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span><span class="title">Document Title</span><span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
```

Instead of:

```
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></span>
<span class="title">Document Title</span>
<span class="subtitle">File type, pdf for example</span>
```

Alternatively, you can remove `wpautop` on that page specifically (without affecting other pages):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_autop', 9);
function remove_autop($content) {
    if ( is_page(227) ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Ha! Never thought to try that! Thanks very much!

Comment: I stumbled upon that trick a couple years ago by accident. Now you know! :-)

Comment: Hi @mevius, I went for the PHP option in the end, seemed more reliable. If I want to add multiple pages to the PHP option, how would I do that, tried the following; 227, 355 and (227), (355), also (227) (355)

Comment: [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) accepts an array of page IDs or slugs: `is_page( array( 227, 355 ) )`

Comment: Hmm, tried this, just kills the page! `add_filter('the_content', 'remove_autop', 9);
function remove_autop($content) {
    if ( is_page( array( 227, 355, 227, 238, 358, 236, 252, 363, 254, 258, 381, 256) ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }
    return $content;
}`

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your `if` statement. Error reporting should tell you this

Comment: Ah, found it. Thanks very much, I have never touched PHP before, so I do have any knowledge of Error reporting. I'll paste the working code in case anyone is looking for the same answer. `add_filter('the_content', 'remove_autop', 9);
function remove_autop($content) {
    if ( is_page( array( 225, 355, 227, 238, 358, 236, 252, 363, 254, 258, 381, 256 ) ) ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }
    return $content;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress seems to be automatically adding a bunch of `br` tags to your output. If you're inputting the menu through the editor, you'll need to make sure you add it as raw HTML. I think WordPress has a filter called `wpautop` that you'll want to disable if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks Nick, this isn't really an option though as the customer of the site will need line breaks enabled.

Comment: You could do a CSS hack, for example: `.item.type-link > br {display: none;}` and forget about all the WordPress nuances.

Comment: That's a good workaround, assuming there are no intentional `<br>` tags in the actual `.subtitle` span. :-)

Comment: The direct descendant selector `a > b` would prevent that from happening :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because in wordpress [click here](http://prntscr.com/a3ossf) there are br (break) tags generating.
You have to remove those. I guess you are using this code in wordpress visual editor. Try to avoid visual editor, instead use their text-editor.

Comment: Hi, the code is being entered via the text-editor not visual-editor

Comment: Then just add the following codes in your functions.php

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

Answer (score 0):

Then just add the following codes in your functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: Would this not be complete nightmare for the customer though. Remember they are only ever going to use visual editor? Just thinking out loud

Comment: You can say it's a bug. You need to use wordpress editor carefully. 
Even if you just toggling between text & visual editor then there might be this type of issues.

By the way, Does this code work for you?